# R, dplyr: Collect unique values for a column, mutate a label based on set intersection

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a large data set, but let us take a toy example to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. I am using `R` and `dplyr`.
I have a table:

```
id  attribute correct
1   a         a
1   b         a
1   c         a
2   d         e
2   e         e
3   d         f
```

From the above, I want to create two columns, `attribute_set` and `label`. To clarify, I want:

```
id  attribute_set   correct   label
1   a, b, c         a         1
2   d, e            e         1
3   d               f         0
```

`attribute_set` should be a collection (any data structure) that has all of the attributes for an `id`. `label` should be 1 if the correct value is in `attribute_set` and 0 otherwise.

Presently, I create `attribute_set` like so:

```
design_mat1 <- design_mat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(attribute_set = paste(unique(attribute), collapse = "|")) %>%
  select(-attribute)
```

I generate `label` like so:

```
design_mat2b <- design_mat2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(correct %in% attribute_set, 1, 0))
```

However, my label works only when there is one element in `attribute_set`. I think I have to `strsplit` on `|` or make `attribute_set` use some other data structure. I have been unable to figure out what alternative data structure to use nor have I been able to get a `strsplit` on `|` solution to work. Any hints/solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After grouping by 'id', we can use `summarise` to `paste` the `unique` elements of 'attribute', while selecting the `first` or `unique` values of 'correct' and 'label' if there is `any` 'correct' elements in 'attribute'

```
library(dplyr)
design_mat %>%
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise(attribute_set = toString(unique(attribute)), 
             correct = first(correct),
             label = +(any(correct %in% attribute)))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     id attribute_set correct label
#  <int> <chr>         <chr>   <int>
#1     1 a, b, c       a           1
#2     2 d, e          e           1
#3     3 d             f           0
```

Or use the 'correct' also in `group_by` and then `summarise` on 'attribute_set' and 'label'

Comment: This is a great solution. Now, if I have 50 more columns (e.g. `col1`, `col2`, etc.) I'd like to include in the result, do I have to do: `col1 = first(col1)`, `col2 = first(col2)`? The problem is, there many be many distinct values for `col1` for one `id`. I'm guessing `first()` just takes the first value for `col1` for a given `id` group..

Comment: @user2205916  If these columns have only one value per 'id', then use those in `group_by` i.e `group_by(id, col1, col2)`  If there are 50 or more columns, `group_by_at(vars(id, matches("^col\\d+")))`   If more than one value fo 'col1', you may need to `paste` the unique values as in `attribute_set`